# Recursively remove filename suffix from files in shell

Tags: unix, deployment, filenames, rename

When we develop locally, we append ".dev" or ".prod" to files that should be made available only to the development/production server respectively.

What I would like to do is; after deploying the site to the server, recursively find all files with the ".dev" suffix (for example) and remove it (renaming the file). How would I go about doing this, preferably entirely in the shell (without scripts) so I can add it to our deployment script?

Our servers run Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: this has already been answered:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171966/bash-rename-extension-recursive

Comment: @alfredodeza: Thanks for pointing that one out - I can't find anything there (other than shell scripts) which do what I want though. Some good answers below, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (not entirely shell-only, requires the `find` and `mv` utilities):

```
find . '(' -name '*.dev' -o -name '*.prod' ')' -type f -execdir sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0%.*}"' '{}' ';'
```

If you have the `rename` and `xargs` utilities, you can speed this up a lot:

```
find . '(' -name '*.dev' -o -name '*.prod' ')' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/\.(dev|prod)$//'
```

Both versions should work with any file name, including file names containing newlines.

Comment: +1, that's better than mine. If you have really strict compatibility needs, though, you might want to be aware that POSIX `find` doesn't have `-execdir` or `-print0`, and I believe `"${0%.dev}"` is a bashism.

Comment: This seems to work well; I replaced 's/\.dev$/.prod/' with 's/\.dev$//' as I'm looking to completely remove the extension. There are no particular compatibility needs, so the dependency on rename/xargs isn't a problem. Thanks!

Comment: The manpage of `sh` says that `sh` knows about suffix removal. `-execdir` could be replaced by `-exec` (which the Linux manpage says is less secure), but `-print0` is impossible to replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in `ls *.dev`; do echo "Old Name $file"; new_name=`echo $file | sed -e 's/dev//'` ; echo "New Name $new_name"; mv $file $new_name; done
```

In an example of something I used recently this code looks for any file that ends with new.xml changes a date in the filename (filenames were of the form xmlEventLog_2010-03-23T11:16:16_PFM_1_1.xml), removes the _new from the name and renames the filename to the new name :

```
for file in `ls *new.xml`; do echo "Old Name $file"; new_name=`echo $file | sed -e 's/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/2010-03-23/g' | sed 's/_new//g'` ; echo "New Name $new_name"; mv $file $new_name; done
```

Is this the type of thing you wanted?

Comment: That doesn't recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: And it doesn't work with filenames containing anything "special" (spaces, newlines, nonprintable characters...).

Comment: just trying to help. won't bother doing that on this site again

Comment: Dude, chill. We were trying to help you improve your answer, which doesn't actually answer the original question. It's not a personal attack on you.

Comment: Because it's not correct. (And I didn't downvote it, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 0):

It's totally untested, but this should work in the POSIX-like shell of your choice:

```
remove-suffix () {
    local filename
    while read filename; do
        mv "$filename" "$(printf %s "$filename" | sed "s/\\.$1\$//")"
    done
}

find -name '*.dev' | remove-suffix .dev
```

Note: In the very unusual case that one or more of your filenames contains a newline character, [this won't work](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
find /fullpath -type f -name "*.dev"|sed 's|\(.*\)\(\.pdf\)|mv & \1.sometag|' | sh
```